# Hide particular payment method if subtotal is zero

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods

We want to hide particular payment method if subtotal is zero.

We are giving 100% discount for some products, so that if customers try to buy those products, then I want to hide some custom payment method [code: hdfc]

Comment: It's magento default functionality. You need to configure from payment configuration settings 'Minimum Order Total'.

Comment: @SohelRana Thanks for reply, unfortunately we are using custom payment method.

Comment: No problem then, Please add a option to system.xml. Magento will automatically handle this.

Comment: @BabyinMagento: check answer for setting `Minimum Order Total`.

Comment: @AnilSuthar Thanks a lot, i am trying your answer and i am sure it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `min_order_total` setting in `system.xml` :

```
<fields>
....

<min_order_total>
    <label>Minimum Order Total</label>
    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
    <sort_order>98</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</min_order_total>
....
</fields>
```

Now you can see a Text box in admin `Minimum Order Total`, set it's value to 1. So this method will not be shown for all orders below order total of 1.

OR if you want to **disable payment method programatically**, use below code :

Magento provides the `isAvailable()` method in the model of the each payment method. This method tell Magento if the corresponding payment method is available or not for checkout.

**Step 1** : Open the `config.xml` in your custom module and do following changes:

```
<config>
 <global>
  <!-- Rewrite the Purchase order model -->
  <payment>
   <rewrite>
    <method_purchaseorder>Myproject_Mymodule_Model_Method_Purchaseorder</method_purchaseorder>
   </rewrite>
  </payment>
 </global>
</config>
```

**Step 2** : Create the new Model file in your custom module at the location: `app/code/local/Myproject/Mymodule/Model/Method/Purchaseorder.php`. 
In this file create the `isAvailable()` method as:

```
<?php
class Myproject_Mymodule_Model_Method_Purchaseorder extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Purchaseorder
{
 /**
  * Check if payment method is available for use
  * 
  * @param type $quote
  * @return boolean
  */
 public function isAvailable($quote = null) {
  //Here write your logic for enabling/disabling the method
  //if this
   return true;
  //else
   rerturn false;
 }
}
```

Referenced from here : [Dynamically Enable/Disable Payment Method](http://www.webspeaks.in/2013/12/dynamically-enabledisable-payment-method-in-magento.html)

Comment: sorry, please check this  : http://pasted.co/f484aa4c

Comment: yes it's correct, Clear cache and check admin for payment method

Answer (score 1):

Override your below form base folder to your theme,

```
frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml
```

and here you put the condition subtotal, For example, I have disabled some payment method for some customer which have customer group id = 1 so,

```
<?php
if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
    $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    $customerId = $customerData->getId();
    $customerCollection =  Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
}
 ?>
<dt id="dt_method_<?php echo $_code ?>">
<?php if(!$oneMethod):?>
    <?php if($_code == "checkmo"){ ?>
        <input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_method->getTitle()) ?>" onclick="payment.switchMethod('<?php echo $_code ?>')"<?php if($this->getSelectedMethodCode()==$_code): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="radio"  <?php if($customerCollection->getGroupId() == 1){ ?>disabled<?php } ?> />
    <?php }else{ ?>
        <input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_method->getTitle()) ?>" onclick="payment.switchMethod('<?php echo $_code ?>')"<?php if($this->getSelectedMethodCode()==$_code): ?> checked="checked"<?php endif; ?> class="radio" />
    <?php } ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <span class="no-display"><input id="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>" value="<?php echo $_code ?>" type="radio" name="payment[method]" checked="checked" class="radio" /></span>
    <?php $oneMethod = $_code; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
    <label for="p_method_<?php echo $_code ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getMethodTitle($_method)) ?> <?php echo $this->getMethodLabelAfterHtml($_method) ?></label>
</dt>
<?php if ($html = $this->getPaymentMethodFormHtml($_method)): ?>
<dd id="dd_method_<?php echo $_code ?>">
    <?php echo $html; ?>
</dd>
```

So here you put your condition of subtotal.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an observer to `payment_method_is_active` event an add your logic there ...

```
<payment_method_is_active>
    <observers>
        <disable_paypal_express>
            <class>[module]/observer</class>
            <method>disablePaypalExpress</method>
        </disable_paypal_express>
    </observers>
</payment_method_is_active>
```

Observer.php

```
public function disablePaypalExpress(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    if (Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName() == 'checkout_cart_index') {
        return;
    }

    $method = $observer->getMethodInstance();
    if ($method->getCode() == 'paypal_express') {
        # your code here
        if (your_check) {
            $result = $observer->getResult();
            $result->isAvailable = false;
        }
    }
}
```