# Magento 1.9 skip payment method step when grandtotal is zero

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, orders, payment-methods, grand-total

I want to *skip*  **payment method** step when **Grandtotal** is *zero* 
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!!

Comment: If your Grand Total is zero, surely your Sub Total would be zero too correct?
That being the case, can you not simply enable Zero Subtotal Checkout in System > Configuration, then in the Payment Methods under the Sales tab in the left hand menu choose Zero Subtotal Checkout? I appreciate it doesnt "skip" the step, but that in itself is a re-confirmation to the user that they do not have to pay anything. [![Zero Subtotal Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVREP.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fVREP.png)

Comment: yes i know that but here payment method not skip

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/157262)

Comment: At what scenario the Grand Total will be zero?. Like based on product item or sub total?

Answer (score 2):

Try this!

```
<?php
require_once(Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Checkout').DS.'OnepageController.php');

class SR_MagentoCommunity_OnepageController extends Mage_Checkout_OnepageController
{
    /**
     * Save checkout billing address
     */
    public function saveBillingAction()
    {
        if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
            return;
        }

        if ($this->isFormkeyValidationOnCheckoutEnabled() && !$this->_validateFormKey()) {
            return;
        }

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing', array());
            $customerAddressId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing_address_id', false);

            if (isset($data['email'])) {
                $data['email'] = trim($data['email']);
            }
            $result = $this->getOnepage()->saveBilling($data, $customerAddressId);

            if (!isset($result['error'])) {
                if ($this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->isVirtual()) {
                    if ($this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getGrandTotal() <= 0) {
                        $paymentData = array('method' => 'free');
                        $this->getOnepage()->savePayment($paymentData);
                        $this->loadLayout('checkout_onepage_review');
                        $result['goto_section'] = 'review';
                        $result['update_section'] = array(
                            'name' => 'review',
                            'html' => $this->_getReviewHtml()
                        );
                    } else {
                        $result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
                        $result['update_section'] = array(
                            'name' => 'payment-method',
                            'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
                        );
                    }
                } elseif (isset($data['use_for_shipping']) && $data['use_for_shipping'] == 1) {
                    $result['goto_section'] = 'shipping_method';
                    $result['update_section'] = array(
                        'name' => 'shipping-method',
                        'html' => $this->_getShippingMethodsHtml()
                    );

                    $result['allow_sections'] = array('shipping');
                    $result['duplicateBillingInfo'] = 'true';
                } else {
                    $result['goto_section'] = 'shipping';
                }
            }

            $this->_prepareDataJSON($result);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Shipping method save action
     */
    public function saveShippingMethodAction()
    {
        if ($this->_expireAjax()) {
            return;
        }

        if ($this->isFormkeyValidationOnCheckoutEnabled() && !$this->_validateFormKey()) {
            return;
        }

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost('shipping_method', '');
            $result = $this->getOnepage()->saveShippingMethod($data);
            // $result will contain error data if shipping method is empty
            if (!$result) {
                Mage::dispatchEvent(
                    'checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method',
                     array(
                          'request' => $this->getRequest(),
                          'quote'   => $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()));
                $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->collectTotals();
                $this->_prepareDataJSON($result);
                if ($this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->getGrandTotal() <= 0) {
                    $paymentData = array('method' => 'free');
                    $this->getOnepage()->savePayment($paymentData);
                    $this->loadLayout('checkout_onepage_review');
                    $result['goto_section'] = 'review';
                    $result['update_section'] = array(
                        'name' => 'review',
                        'html' => $this->_getReviewHtml()
                    );
                } else {
                    $result['goto_section'] = 'payment';
                    $result['update_section'] = array(
                        'name' => 'payment-method',
                        'html' => $this->_getPaymentMethodsHtml()
                    );
                }
            }
            $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->collectTotals()->save();
            $this->_prepareDataJSON($result);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create order action
     */
    public function saveOrderAction()
    {
        $this->getOnepage()->getQuote()->collectTotals()->save();
        return parent::saveOrderAction();
    }
}
```

**Overwrite Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Payment class:**

```
<blocks>
    <checkout>
        <rewrite>
            <onepage_payment>SR_MagentoCommunity_Block_Onepage_Payment</onepage_payment>
        </rewrite>
    </checkout>
</blocks>
```

> app/code/local/SR/MagentoCommunity/Block/Onepage/Payment.php

```
<?php

class SR_MagentoCommunity_Block_Onepage_Payment extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Payment
{
    /**
     * Retrieve is allow and show block
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isShow()
    {

        if ($this->getGrandTotal() <= 0) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private function getGrandTotal()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal();
    }
}
```

Finally, overwrite

> skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js

```
ShippingMethod.prototype.nextStep = function(transport){
    var response = transport.responseJSON || transport.responseText.evalJSON(true) || {};

    if (response.error) {
        alert(response.message.stripTags().toString());
        return false;
    }

    if (response.update_section) {
        $('checkout-'+response.update_section.name+'-load').update(response.update_section.html);
    }

    if (response.goto_section) {
        checkout.gotoSection(response.goto_section, true);
        checkout.reloadProgressBlock();
        return;
    }

    payment.initWhatIsCvvListeners();

    if (response.payment_methods_html) {
        $('checkout-payment-method-load').update(response.payment_methods_html);
    }

    checkout.setShippingMethod();
};

Review.prototype.save = function(){
    if (checkout.loadWaiting!=false) return;
    checkout.setLoadWaiting('review');
    if (!$('#co-payment-form')) {
        var params = 'method=free';
    } else {
        var params = Form.serialize(payment.form);
    }


    if (this.agreementsForm) {
        params += '&'+Form.serialize(this.agreementsForm);
    }
    params.save = true;
    new Ajax.Request(
        this.saveUrl,
        {
            method:'post',
            parameters:params,
            onComplete: this.onComplete,
            onSuccess: this.onSave,
            onFailure: checkout.ajaxFailure.bind(checkout)
        }
    );
};
```

**[Update]**

**How you overwrite opcheckout.js?**

> skin/frontend/base/default/js/rewriteopcheckout.js

```
ShippingMethod.prototype.nextStep = function(transport){
    var response = transport.responseJSON || transport.responseText.evalJSON(true) || {};

    if (response.error) {
        alert(response.message.stripTags().toString());
        return false;
    }

    if (response.update_section) {
        $('checkout-'+response.update_section.name+'-load').update(response.update_section.html);
    }

    if (response.goto_section) {
        checkout.gotoSection(response.goto_section, true);
        checkout.reloadProgressBlock();
        return;
    }

    payment.initWhatIsCvvListeners();

    if (response.payment_methods_html) {
        $('checkout-payment-method-load').update(response.payment_methods_html);
    }

    checkout.setShippingMethod();
};

Review.prototype.save = function(){
    if (checkout.loadWaiting!=false) return;
    checkout.setLoadWaiting('review');
    if (!$('#co-payment-form')) {
        var params = 'method=free';
    } else {
        var params = Form.serialize(payment.form);
    }


    if (this.agreementsForm) {
        params += '&'+Form.serialize(this.agreementsForm);
    }
    params.save = true;
    new Ajax.Request(
        this.saveUrl,
        {
            method:'post',
            parameters:params,
            onComplete: this.onComplete,
            onSuccess: this.onSave,
            onFailure: checkout.ajaxFailure.bind(checkout)
        }
    );
};
```

Now open **checkout/onepage.phtml** template in your current theme. Ex. my case is default **rwd/default**.

> app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/checkout/onepage.phtml

Add following line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('js/rewriteopcheckout.js') ?>"></script>
```

[image]

I have tested with M1.9.4.1 with the fresh installation with sample data.

Comment: So you dont want to show payment step?

Comment: yes right i want to payment step skip when grand total is zero

Comment: Check updated answer

Comment: you have tested your code? when grand total is zero then above code is working?

Comment: Did you checked that? working fine 1.9.4.1

Comment: Check carefully my updated answer.

Comment: i have add your js code in on opcheckout.js but shipping step continue button not working

Comment: What is the console error?

Comment: not any console error shipping step continue button not working

Comment: Not sure how you add js customization. Still working fine with rwd theme. Check the updated answer. Also, can you check with a fresh installation, then you can find out where you made a mistake.

Comment: i have updated but not working for me error is: shipping method step is not continue

Comment: Did you checked fresh installation?

Comment: no i have check in my theme

Comment: Suggestion: you can try using fresh installation, if it works for you then compare with your custom theme.

Answer (score 0):

Affected file for above described problem is

> {Magento-Root-Folder}/app/design/frontend/{YourTheme}/default/template/checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml

note that if folder 'checkout' is not available in your template folder, make sure to copy it from `{Magento-Root-Folder}/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout` to your template folder; make sure you keep the structure identical

inside this file (methods.phtml) we actually look through available payments (around line 45), this is where we need to adjust a little.

1) place this line anywhere on top of your file to get current quote data (we will need it in step 2)

```
$quote_data = Mage::helper('checkout')->getQuote()->getData();
```

it will contain **$quote_data[grand_total]**

2) search for the payment methods iterating around line 45

```
foreach ($methods as $_method):
    $_code = $_method->getCode();
```

we need to check $_code ('free' means Zero Subtotal Checkout) and add a simple if clause inside the same foreach:

```
if ($_code == "free" && $quote_data[grand_total] < 1) { // if payment method is free and grand total '0'
    // this is where your action should happen
    $class_show_pm = ""; // will be used to show/hide 'dt' tag
    $radio_checked = "checked"; // will be used to enable/disable radio button
    $radio_onclick = "payment.switchMethod(" .$_code .")"; // will be used to load js code
} else {
    $class_show_pm = "none";
    $radio_checked = "";
    $radio_onclick = "";
}
```

You can check out this [Skip Payment Step if Grand Total 0](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/190401/skip-payment-step-if-grand-total-0) too

I hope this helps

Comment: Yes you can give it a try